# How to pass args to application from Eclipse Maven Run configurations

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, arguments

I have a Java / Maven project in Eclipse 2023-06. If I want to run the application, I am using a run configuration based on Maven, as depicted in below picture. I can't figure out how to pass an argument to the application - in other words, arguments passed to "*public static void main(String[] args)*" - without defining a environment variable in the Run Configurations dialog

[image: Eclipse Run Configurations]

like it is possible to define it in the Java Application dialog

[image: Java Application Run Configuration]

Is there a way to do this directly without checking environment variables?

Comment: Maven is to build your application. To run it use a _Java Application_ instead of a _Maven Build_ launch configuration. Otherwise, if you really want run it via Maven and not directly as a _Java Application_, show your `pom.xml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running Maven, any parameters are passed to the Maven build. If, like in your case, you have a plugin which also executes the application, then you have to check the plugin's documentation to see how arguments have to be passed.

The [javafx-maven-plugin](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin#javafxrun-options) has a `commandlineArgs` option which you can use to set application arguments, as shown in the example:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.8</version>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>org.openjfx.hellofx/org.openjfx.App</mainClass>
        <commandlineArgs>foo</commandlineArgs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

To make the arguments configurable in the Eclipse launch configuration, you can use a Maven property here:

```
<commandlineArgs>${yourapp.commandlineArgs}</commandlineArgs>
```

and then define `yourapp.commandlineArgs` in the parameters table in the launch configuration's main tab.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get this or it doesn't work for me. To add the line in pom.xml is clear, but if I run in main 
        if(args.length > 0) {
   for(int i=0; i<args.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(args[i]);
   }
  }
  
I get nothing on the console

Comment: It worked.  I overlooked it since the console was a mess due to output from various threads.